# Issue in installing Jenkins when executing war file

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 2.73.1 in Windows. when executing below command to install Jenkins,

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

I get following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
[33mOct 28, 2017 12:01:28 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\winstone\jenkins.war
[0mOct 28, 2017 12:01:28 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @1490ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:28 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
[33mOct 28, 2017 12:01:28 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
[0mOct 28, 2017 12:01:28 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:31 AM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:31 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:31 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:31 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\user\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@4bdeaabb{/,file:///C:/Users/user/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\user\.jenkins\war}
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStop
INFO: Stopped ServerConnector@7a5ceedd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper stopScavenging
INFO: Stopped scavenging
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM hudson.WebAppMain contextDestroyed
INFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:898)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:873)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1507)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:927)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:307)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:167)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)

Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@4bdeaabb{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\user\.jenkins\war}
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Oct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more
[31mOct 28, 2017 12:01:33 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more

[0m
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's a few things that I'm seeing in your stack trace that seem very likely to cause a problem. notably these two:

```
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
```

and

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Basically, there's two issues here, the first being that the port your Jenkins is trying to bind to is already in use, try and figure out what's using the port jetty would want to bind to (usually either 80 or 8080, if my memory serves).

The second is an issue saying it can't find a class for an exception it was trying to throw, I think.

I'm not sure how that'd happen, I'd free up the port and see if that issue goes away, and if not figure out why that class is missing from your classpath

Answer (score 9):

As per my analysis, Jenkins by default will try to use port number as 8080. You are facing this issue because the port number(8080) has been already occupied with the some other process like tomcat or oracle or something else.

This problem solved when I have passed my own port number while running the jenkins.war.  It ran successfully and downloaded all the metadata. You can see the below command how am I passing the port,

for **HTTP**:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

for **HTTPS**:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

**Note:** Initially I have even faced the ClassNotFountException. I din't get any exception when I tried with the new port number.

Answer (score 6):

(Solved)

Right, This errors occurs when you are trying to start the jenkins using `java -jar jenkins.war` on port 8080 (by default).

> Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad

first check the port 8080 using these steps >

**Step 1:** 
Run command-line as an Administrator. Then run the below mention
command.

netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8016

TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8016
```

take the PID (process identifier) : **8016** (it will be different in your system)

then execute this command after identify the PID (8016).

**Step 2:**

```
taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
```

again run netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber and check either port is closed or not.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 2):

Update the port as in `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue. Steps resolved the issue for me are below:

1. Check if Tomcat service is up and running. If not then please start it first.
2. in my case STS was using default tomcat. I have ended that process.
3. executed the command > java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=9090

It worked for me.