# Issue in Jenkins when executing war file command

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to integrate c# selenium automation with Jenkins. I installed jenkins and I can launch the jenkins on Chrome as a Admin. But I see below issue when I run this command on command prompt
    
        `$ java -jar jenkins.war`

I am currently using : windows 10 , jdk1.8.0_151 ,  Jenkins 2.94 
I am copying complete error here.

```
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
[33mDec 14, 2017 8:39:13 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\winstone\jenkins.war
[0mDec 14, 2017 8:39:13 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @708ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:13 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
[33mDec 14, 2017 8:39:13 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
[0mDec 14, 2017 8:39:13 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:19 AM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:19 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:19 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:19 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\Mike\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@6f53b8a{/,file:///C:/Users/Mike/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\Mike\.jenkins\war}
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStop
INFO: Stopped ServerConnector@4e5ed836{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper stopScavenging
INFO: Stopped scavenging
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM hudson.WebAppMain contextDestroyed
INFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:898)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:873)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1507)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:927)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:307)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:167)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)

Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@6f53b8a{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\Mike\.jenkins\war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Dec 14, 2017 8:39:20 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more
        [31mDec 14, 2017 8:39:21 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        ... 7 more
```

I am not sure why "java -jar jenkins.war" command throwing error.

I followed this : [Issue in installing Jenkins when executing war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981658/issue-in-installing-jenkins-when-executing-war-file)    but not helping me.

Comment: Is there more to the error than that?

Comment: yes added here, thanks

Comment: some more findings : above issue happens when I run java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080  but things run fine when I run java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090 but in this case I can not login to Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same issue
Open the Jenkins.xml
Search --httpPort=8080 and replace the 8080 with the new port number NOT IN USE that you wish (9090 for example)
open cmd in admin mode
X:\Jenkins_generic>java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090

Jenkins starts without issues

Comment: That is something userful for people who will land here for this question (could be an answer for folks), I was aware of this solution before I post this question out here, but my problem was something different and I also posted an answer for additional help. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I troubleshoot the issue : Mistakenly I also downloaded "windows" installer (from here https://jenkins.io/download/)  and tried to run Jenkins on that.

But I had to install only "Generic java package .war" file and then give the java -jar jenkins.war , now issue seems resolved in my end.

Other post also saying to download Tomcat Apache for port issue , I am not quite sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have resolved it by terminating the ports process id which is used by Jenkins

> run following commands in cmd **run as an administrator**

1. `netstat -a -o -n`  it will list down you used port numbers and their process ids
2. `taskkill /F /PID`   run to kill the port number by process id
   **PID means your process id**
3. `java -jar Jenkins.war --enable-future-java` to run your .war file from cmd